# Why is 64bit Ubuntu running Slower?

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, 64bit, 32bit, cpu-architecture

I have 2 mostly identical machines, and Acer and a Lenovo, both with Intel Atom 230 CPU @ 1.60GHz and 1GB of DDR2 RAM. The acer has a fresh install of 64Bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS while the Lenovo has the 32Bit version of the same.

Both systems are basically used as a NAS and have plenty of memory free. The new Acer machine is noticeably slower than the Lenovo, so I decided to run CPU stress tests.

Running `sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=5000 run` on both machines I get very different results. The 32Bit Lenovo finishes in just over 28 seconds while 64Bit Acer takes over 37 seconds! I would generally dismiss synthetic tests, but it just "feel" slower.

Of course they are 2 different machines, but they were basically same price, have identical CPU, memory, and HD specs, and neither one of them is throttling the CPU, as they are both running rather cool.

I tried a few other CPU benchmarks with the same result. I thought 64bit was supposed to be faster, especially for math centric problems, like the once used for synthetic CPU tests. What am I missing here????

Answer (score 2):

Short: it depends on what type of test you are running, and whether the data fits into 32-bits and does not depend upon extended precision *software* manipulations.  There are a lot of pros/cons, and without thorough testing by *you*, the information will be only second-hand.

Further reading:

- [Are 64-bit Binaries Really Slower than 32-bit Binaries?](http://www.osnews.com/story/5768/Are_64-bit_Binaries_Really_Slower_than_32-bit_Binaries_)
- [Why 64Bit version app is much slower than 32Bit version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331660/why-64bit-version-app-is-much-slower-than-32bit-version)
- [64bit vs 32bit benchmarks & integer maths & PT8](http://www.passmark.com/forum/showthread.php?3348-64bit-vs-32bit-benchmarks-amp-integer-maths-amp-PT8)